# Internal modules error on debugging node application

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, node-streams, enoent

I'm trying to debug node application, I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.5** and **nodejs 6.10.2**. The app configuration seems to be ok, actually the application is running but when I try to debug the application I'm facing this error :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.5\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=60858 --nolazy server.js

Debugger listening on [::]:60858 
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\My\Project\Working\Folder\myapp\internal\streams\lazy_transform.js'
 at Error (native)
 at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
 at eval (eval at <anonymous> (internal/streams/lazy_transform.js:1:1), <anonymous>:49:17)
 at eval (eval at <anonymous> (internal/streams/lazy_transform.js:1:1), <anonymous>:73:5)
 at internal/streams/lazy_transform.js:1:1
 at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:25:33)
 at runInThisContext (bootstrap_node.js:404:19)
 at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:491:18)
 at NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:437:18)
 at crypto.js:24:23
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'c:\\\My\\Project\\Working\\Folder\\myapp\\internal\\streams\\lazy_transform.js' }
```

And other internals: **child_process.js**, **socket_list.js** and **cluster.js**

1. Could be something related to wrong debugger version ?
2. Missing some configuration ?

Thank you in advice,

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node 6.* debugging is only supported since Idea 2016.2. V8 debugging protocol has changed dramatically since the time Idea 14 was released.
You have to either upgrade Idea or downgrade Node.js... to v 4.* may be, or even to 0.10

Comment: Hi @lena, I did downgrade of nodejs ( to 4.x, I tested many versions ) and the error persists but the debugger is working. At the moment this is the best solution but I will also test the upgrade of IntelliJ. Thank you !